# set up a shortcut / keybinding under GNU/Linux with altGr key (but Autokey nor other methods reconize the key)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, archlinux, hotkeys, autokey

I need to do a simple shortcut and this problem is driving me crazy. 
Whenever I press AltGR+Backspace I would like to simulate a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT(arrow)</kbd>.

The thing is that AutoKey doesn't get the <kbd>AltGR</kbd> input (and neither xbindkeys or other methods).

I tried to do it with xbindkeys but <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is seen as a "Mod5 + ISO_Level3_Shift" input and despite that I can't figure out how to do it, this doesn't work:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown Left' 'keyup Control_L'"
    m:0x80 + c:22
    Mod5 + BackSpace
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Stackoverflow is _not_ a forum! There are questions and there are answers. If you have found an _answer_ to _question_, post it as one! Do NOT edit your _question_ to insert an answer into it, all while adding a (solved) to the title.

Comment: sorry I'll modify the post and add the solution as an answer, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution with xbindkeys, I needed to insert "+ Release" after the combination of keys, so:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key Left' 'keyup Control_L'"
    Mod5 + BackSpace + Release
```